# Unique combinations in two ranges

Tags: google-sheets

I have a single-column range (let's call it `range1`) that looks like this:

```
ABC
DEF
GEH
```

I also have another single-column range called `range2`:

```
123
456
789
```

I desire a function that would output the following two-column range:

```
ABC | 123
ABC | 456
ABC | 789
DEF | 123
DEF | 456
DEF | 789
GEH | 123
GEH | 456
GEH | 789
```

**My Current Solution**

I have the following script:

```
function categorize_and_collate(range1, range2) {
  output = []
  for (i = 0; i < range1.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < range2.length; j++) {
      if (range1[i] != "" && range2[j] != "") {
        output.push([String(range1[i]), String(range2[j])])
      }
    }
  }

  return output
}
```

If we assume that `range1` is `A1:A3` and `range2` is `B1:B3`, then the following:

```
=categorize_and_collate("A1:A3", "B1:B3")
```

...outputs I'd expect:

```
ABC | 123
ABC | 456
ABC | 789
DEF | 123
DEF | 456
DEF | 789
GEH | 123
GEH | 456
GEH | 789
```

Best part: if I add an arbitrary number of rows to either column, this function still works.

- Is there a non-script-based method of accomplishing this?
- If a script is the only way to go, is this the best way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google Spreadsheet Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en&ref_topic=3105706&vid=1-635788148011464934-3806322323)... no. But you could calculate all the ways to do that! This means that yes, a script is the only way to do it.

Since you only need to combine two columns you only have two for loops. Which you have. So yeah your script is about as simple as it gets for it. Good job!